# How to setup a Local React App on Raspberrypi?

Tags: python, node.js, reactjs, raspberry-pi, cors

I'm having some troubles setting up my React App (front, with Python/PgSQL back) on my Pi after failing to build it from there (not enough memory), let me explain :

**Before :**

- Everything was on the Pi : Python, Pg database, React App.
- Use VSCode from Windows PC with SSH connexion to the Pi.
- Run with `npm start` at `raspberrypi.lan:3000` (or `192.168.0.14:3000`, the Pi IP).

Everything was fine since i tried to improve it as i wanted to reach the app directly from
`raspberrypi.lan`

So is installed an Apache server then i followed some tutorials telling me that i just have to run **npm run build** and copy/paste the `build` folder in `/var/www/html`, what i did.

Awesome, it's working great !!

**Now :**

- React code moved on Windows PC.
- Use VSCode from Windows PC locally.
- Dev (PC) run with `npm start` at `localhost:3000`.
- Prod (Pi) run on Apache serveur at `raspberrypi.lan`.
- Build with `npm run build`.
- Transfert generated `build` folder by ftp to the Pi in `/var/www/html`

  *=> not really glamorous, if someone knows how to do it better…*.

Again, that's working good … except that …

When i call my Python API (remember, on the PI, at `raspberrypi.lan:5000`), i have two behaviors :

- Dev (PC) :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://raspberrypi.lan/api/product/list' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy

- Prod (PI) :

> You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.

I know what those mean but i don't know how to fix them properly.
You can notice that on Prod, the calls answers OK 200 but something seams missing.
If i add the API port i'm facing the CORS policy this time in Prod (too) :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://raspberrypi.lan:5000/api/product/list' from origin 'http://raspberrypi.lan' has been blocked by CORS policy

So here i am asking you :

**How to setup those babies so i can reach the API from both PC and Pi sides ?**

Thanks in advance and sorry for my approximative english.

Comment: Have you read and understood https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS?

Comment: @jub0bs As i said, i know what it is, i just don't know how to configure it especially in python that i know absolutely nothing

Answer (score -2):

Well,

Especially thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64780136/1977916) i used to fix it using `flask_cors` Python library and ending up with the exact same situation than the other user.